# Разделить строку через заглавную букву utf-8

Tags: php, строки

upd. с латиницей так же как и с кириллицей
<strike>меня есть код который нормально работает с латиницей, но при utf-8</strike> убирает первую букву слова, Array ( [0] => привет [1] => имон [2] => оробка )

```
$capitals = array("Л","К");
$word_break = "приветЛимонКоробка";
$word_break = str_replace($capitals, '/',$word_break);
```

подскажите пожалуйста как быть без регулярных выражений

Comment: А почему без регулярных выражений?

Comment: Зачем писать неправду? Этот код будет работать с латиницей точно так же. Поскольку тупо заменяет указанные буквы на слеш.

Comment: @Ипатьев зачем мне писать неправду?) с латиницей массив заполняется словами с первой буквы, ничего не обрезается.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/JcIUb

Comment: @Ипатьев вот блин, да, прошу прощения

Comment: @Эдуард условие задания, думала может найти вхождение заглавной буквы и закончить прописной, но не могу понять как сформулировать такое выражение - определить что буква заглавная через ctype_upper например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно надо делать такое на регулярках, но если очень хочется без них вариант:

```
$capitals = array("Л","К");
$word_break = "приветЛимонКоробка";

foreach($capitals as $e){
    $word_break=str_replace($e, '/'.$e, $word_break);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример можно немного модифицировать:

```
$capitals = array("~(Л)~", "~(К)~");
$word_break = "приветЛимонКоробка";
$word_break = preg_replace($capitals, '/$1', $word_break);

echo $word_break; // привет/Лимон/Коробка
```

---

А если привязка нужна не к конкретным буквам, а ко всем прописным, то можно так:

```
$word_break = "приветЛимонКоробка";
$word_break = preg_replace('~[А-ЯЁ]~u', '/$0', $word_break);

echo $word_break; // привет/Лимон/Коробка
```